# How to create access token for hotmail using oauth API 2.0

Tags: java

I am new to Oauth API 2.0, so I want to create access token for hotmail using Oauth API 2.0 in java. Can you please help me.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Here, we expect you to demonstrate minimal effort before asking a question. Can you edit your post to show us what you have done so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the java library [Scribe](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java). It has many examples to help you deal with oauth.